# Memristor equations

Tags: math, memristor

I was working with memristors and wondering about their equations. If the memristor resistance(or memristance) is based on the amount of charge, the memristance should equal:

$$M(t)=\int(C(t))dt$$ or $$M(t)=q(t)$$

where C(t) is the current function and q(t) is the charge function.

However it seems like this is not the case like in the Wikipedia article on memristors. Please help me!

Comment: When you say "C(t) is the current function", do you mean that the unit of C is A (Amperes), and the integral over time is then As (Amperes times seconds)? If so, this would not be the definition of memristance. Memristance has the same basic units as resistance (V/A), even though a memristor will not keep its value once the voltage or current changes. It won't work out to say M(t)=q(t), because you would end up saying V/A=As

Comment: @zebonaut Then what is the equation? Isn't it proportional to the charge?

Answer (score 1):

Writing M(t) alone is misleading, you should always explicitate the "q", i.e. M(q(t)) or M(q).
This shows you already one thing: M does *not* vary directly with time, but with q, hence the formula showed on the wiki in the [theory section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memristor#Theory), which is really nothing but math to simplify the concept and give more insight on the memristor. 
It's important to understand the definition of the memristor(still quoting the wiki): 
"Each memristor is characterized by its memristance function describing the **charge-dependent rate of change of flux with charge**".